# Elementary proof of the irreducibility of $T^4 - a T - 1$ in $\mathbf{Q}[T]$ when $a\in\mathbf{Z}-\{0\}$

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

This is from the exercises of *Bourbaki, Algèbre, Chapitre V*, first exercise of the exercises concerning the second paragraph of the fifth chapter. (p. 140.)

> As Gauss Lemma ("if your gcd is invertible then you are irreducible in $\mathbf{Q}[T]$ if and only you are irreducible in  $\mathbf{Q}[T]$") is not stated in any chapter of Bourbaki's *Algèbre*, I would like to prove the polynomial's irreducibility without it, and without using any gcd of coefficients of a polynomial, in an *elementary way.*

Below is what I did using Gauss Lemma, plus what I tried to do without it, without success (case where the polynomial is product of two degree $2$ rational polynomials)

One has to show that $P = T^4 - a T - 1$ is irreducible in $\mathbf{Q}[T]$ when $a\in\mathbf{Z}-\{0\}$. Obviously, as the gcd of $P$'s coefficients is $1$, it suffice to show that $P$ is irreducible in $\mathbf{Z}[T]$.

Now as $P$ as no integer root. Let $r = \frac{p}{q}$ be a rational root, with $q\not=0$ and $p\wedge q = 1$. Then, multiplying both members of the equation $P(r)=0$ by $q^4$ gives $p^4 - a p q^3 - q^4 = 0$, that is, $p^4 = q^3 (ap+q)$. Let $p'$ be a prime dividing $p$. Then $p'$ divides either $q^3$ and then $q$, either $ap+q$ and then $q$. So $p'$ divides $q$. If there is a prime number dividing $p$, it divides $q$ and then $p\wedge q \not= 1$ which is absurd, showing that no prime number divides $p$, that is that $p\in\{0,\pm 1\}$. If $p=0$, then $r=0$ and $0 = P(r) = P(0) = 1$, absurd. If $p = \pm 1$ then $1 = \pm q^3(a+q)$ showing that $q\in\mathbf{Z}^{\times}$, that is, that $q = \pm 1$. This shows that $r = \pm 1$. But then $0 = P(r) = 1 \pm a - 1 = \pm a$, absurd.

If $P$ is reducible, then $P = P_1 P_2$ with the $P_i$'s in $\mathbf{Z}[T]$, of degree $2$ and with leading coefficient $1$. Say $P_1 = T^2 + \alpha T + \beta$ and $P_2 = T^2 + \gamma T + \delta$. This leads to the system $$(S) \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\alpha + \gamma & = & 0 \\
\beta + \delta + \alpha \gamma & = & 0 \\
\alpha \delta + \beta \gamma & = & -a \\
\beta\delta & = & -1 \\
\end{array}\right.$$ Fourth equation implies that $\beta, \delta = \pm 1$ and that they have opposite sign, implying also that $\beta = - \delta$. Then second equation implies that $\alpha \gamma = 0$. Then the first equation implies that both $\alpha,\gamma$ are equal to $0$. Up to a permutation of $1$ and $2$, we have therefore $P_1 = T^2 +1$ and mainly $P_2 = T^2 - 1$, leading to a contradiction, as we saw that $P$ has no root in $\mathbf{Z}$. I am a bit puzzled by the fact that $a$ didn't play any role in the second case, but fine, $P = T^4 - a T - 1$ is irreducible in $\mathbf{Q}[T]$. But...

I have tried to write $P = P_1 P_2$ as before, but with the $P_i$'s with rational coefficients, getting a system (S) with this time $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta\in\mathbf{Q}$, and then trying to get a contradiction, but without success... Any advice ? Thx !

Comment: If the lemma (or something similar) is not in the book anywhere, I would throw the book out.

Comment: @user2345215 FYI, Bourbaki is composed in many series of books (algebra, commutative algebra etc). The Gauss Lemma is the commutative algebra series, coming after the algebra series. The exercise means to you have to prove the irr of $P$ without using Gauss Lemma.

Comment: @RobertGreen Alright then.

Comment: @user2345215 Np, you made me laugh so much ! ;-)

Comment: @EricFlorentNoube Edit your question to put its purpose upfront.

Comment: Are you aware that one can prove a very simple form of Gauss' Lemma in 2 lines (not using "contents"), and this will complete your proof?

Comment: The  one with ideals generated by coefficients ? If so, yes, but how does it imply a contradiction from writing $P = P_1 P_2$ with $P_1$ and $P_2$ with rational coefficients.

Comment: @Eric No, more elementary, e.g. see [this one.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/871823/242) If you like I can simplify it to high-school level and post it here (e.g. eliminating  $\,R[x]/p \cong (R/p)[x]\,$ if that is not familiar). That's the essence of Gauss's Lemma.

Comment: @Eric Ah, I misread what you needed. If you only need Gauss's Lemma to finish it, then you can use the very simple form that I linked.

Comment: @BillDubuque Yeah, I know this one. Actually, as it is written in the question, I would like to prove irr over Q without passing by irr over Z (that I know to proof, and I also know to use to get irr over Q). I showed that P has no rational roots, and it remains to show that I have a contraction if $P = P_1 P_2$ with $P_i$'s of degree $2$ and with rational coefficients. This is what I do to succeed to show. Look at system (S) in my coeff, but with $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ rational. This "rational" system must lead to a contradiction, as it did when $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ were in Z.

Comment: @BillDubuque No worries Bill, but I do no need Gauss Lemma to finish, read my very previous comment

Comment: I'd just like to point out that prime numbers *have* in fact been introduced at this point in Bourbaki. So it may well be the case that they expect you to reduce modulo some prime number in lieu of using Gauss's Lemma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

> Lemma 2. -- Let $f,g,$ and $h$ be unitary polynomials in $\mathbf{Q}[X]$ such that $f = gh$. Si $f$ has integer coefficients, so do $g$ and $h$.

This is in *Algèbre*, Bourbaki. Chapitre 5, p A.5.78, before your exercise. So that your proof becomes "Bourbaki-legal", so to speak, modulo the use of this lemma at the beginning of your proof, no worries !

As you may see reduction modulo a prime $p$ is used, as well as integrity of $\mathbf{F}_p [X]$. The translation goes as follows :

> Let $a$ (resp. $b$) the smallest integer $\alpha \geq 1$ (resp $\beta\geq 1$) such that $\alpha g$ (resp. $\beta j$) has integer coefficients ; let us set $g' = ag$ and $h' = bh$ and let us show *ab absurdo* that $a = b = 1$. If not, a prime divisor $p$ of $ab$ would exist. If $u\in\mathbf{Z}[X]$ note $\overline{u}$ le polynomial in $\mathbf{F}_p [X]$ obtained by reducing modulo $p$ the coefficients of $u$. We have $g'h' = abf$, so that $\overline{g'} \overline{h'} = 0$. As the ring $\mathbf{F}_p [X]$ is a domain (IV, p.9, prop. 8), we have therefore $\overline{g'} = 0$ or $\overline{h'} = 0$. Put differently, $p$ divides all coefficients of $g'$ or all coefficients of $h'$, a contradiction with the hypothesis we made.

Finally, IV, p.9, prop. 8 is just the proposition saying that if $A$ is a domain, so is $A[(X_i)_{i\in I}]$

Comment: Thx a lot, that's perfect !

Comment: That's a bit confusing, because it's in Section V.11 and the exercise corresponds to Section V.2. It's true that it appears at the end of Chapter V, but are you really supposed to use things from later in the chapter? In any case, it makes sense to use it here if you can.

Comment: @user208259 Yeah, I thought about that, do you read everything and then you do all exercises, or do you do exercises section per section ?... It depends. Here, I would recommend the first. But I would be really curious to see a proof not at least using this, indeed.